# Why is my destination-out filling in white?

Tags: javascript, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

So I have been playing with particle systems a lot lately. I was going to try to make some fireworks and in the process of learning how to make a "trail" I got stuck. As far as I understand destination-out for globalcompositeoperation should put a black transparent image over the canvas if my fill style is rgba(0,0,0,0.5);. However, strangely when I do this it paints the canvas white. I have no idea why or what I am doing wrong here. Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/tourn171/pen/NPjxBP?editors=001)

```js
window.reqFrame = (function() {
  return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var canvas, ctx;
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;
particles = [];


function particle() {
  this.x = W / 2;
  this.y = H / 2;
  this.vx = -4;
  this.c = "#FF0000";
}

particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x - 4, this.y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.stroke()
}

particle.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
}


function loop() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  particles[0].draw();
  particles[0].update();
  reqFrame(loop);
}

function paintRect(color, x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

function paintCanvas(color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;
  particles.push(new particle());
  loop();

}

init();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

to what I am working on. This one though is just me working with global composite so....... yeah.

Comment: convert rgba(0,0,0,0.5) to hex

Comment: You forgot to use beginPath() when drawing a new line.
I fixed that and used globalAlpha to have your progressive erasing effect : 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yybJQd